# EaselJS - Android WebView does not clear old graphics drawn

Tags: android, easeljs

I am using EaselJS to render some graphics rectangles onto a shape in easelJS and inside WebView in Android. But when the Shape on which the graphics is drawn moves the old drawn rectangles remain where they are as if printed fixed on the screen. However on Chrome on my desktop everything works fine with same HTML5. I have tried `stage.clear()`, `webView.clearcache` but none of them seem to work. Any idea what could be the issue?

Android code below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(24);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //webSettingssetBackgroundColor(0);
    //webSettings.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    //webSettings.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    myWebView.clearView();
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

HTML5 code below:

```
var shape1 = new createjs.Shape();
shape1.color = baseColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * (baseColors.length))];
shape1.graphics.beginFill(shape1.color).drawRect(0, 0, 30,30);
stage.addChild(shape1);
stage.update();
```

Comment: I don't know why this is, but in case you are also looking for a quick fix, add another shape as a background, so the stage is not transparent

Comment: Thanks,As a quick fix for now I have just added another black background shape below all the rectangle shapes and added to stage and it works fine